# how to allow only one IAM user to be able to upload files to S3 without it being able to list the directories in S3 bucket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, permissions

in policy of a IAM user i added:

```
    {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PermissionForObjectOperations",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:putObject"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and when i try to upload a file using below code:

```
var params = {
    Body: 'some body',
    Bucket: 'my-bucket-name',
    Key: 'exampleobject',
    ServerSideEncryption: 'AES256',
    Tagging: 'key1=value1&key2=value2'
};
s3.putObject(params, function(err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

i get the following error:

> message: 'Access Denied',   code: 'AccessDenied',

Comment: i needed to add "s3:PutObjectTagging"

Answer (score 0):

i needed to add "s3:PutObjectTagging"